# Apache responds to anything as if GET / is sent

Tags: apache-http-server, http

Apache exposes some strange behaviour, it seems to react to anything as if a `GET /` was sent, instead of giving me a "Bad Request" error:

```
[bf@bf-laptop-tbwb ~]$ telnet www.myserver.com 80
Trying 1.2.3.4...
Connected to www.myserver.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
jkl;
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
...
```

I expect it to give me a 400 Bad Request HTTP error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I suspect you are getting a `501 Method not implemented` in html format, just look further in the response

You would get `400 Bad request` if you would call an existing method with malformex syntax (try for example `GET -`)

But since you call an invalid method, you get 501

Comment: No, I get the index file. I don't even get response headers. Doing the same with `www.google.com` gives me a 400.